# Grafana dashboard variable - handling NULL values in Query-based variable

Tags: mysql, grafana, dashboard, sql-null, grafana-variable

I've created a Grafana dashboard variable (multi-select enabled) based on a MySQL query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT(my_field) from my_table
```

This field has about 12 options, one of them being a NULL value. When editing my dashboard widgets, I include a SQL constraint similar to:

```sql
... WHERE my_field IN ($my_variable)
```

This almost works well, except for the NULLs. Grafana is translating the NULL to `''`, and NULL isn't supported in an `IN (...)` statement anyway.

Any recommendations on how to handle this to work with NULLs?

Answer (score 3):

You could extend condition:

```
WHERE my_field IN ($my_variable) OR my_field IS NULL;
```

---

> Grafana is translating the NULL to ''

```
WHERE COALESCE(my_field, '') IN ($my_variable)
```

Comment: Thanks, the trouble with this approach is that NULL isn't always selected in the dashboard as an option for the variable. I essentially need the IS NULL clause to be conditional if a null value is selected in the list of options in the dashboard drop down.

Comment: @radicand There are other options